# retrieve unique id for just added row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, dataset

I am new to asp.net. I am executing a simple insert query via a SQL command. Now I want to retrieve the unique id for this newly inserted row and store it in an array. I do not know how to approach this problem.

My code

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvuserdata.Rows)
        {

            string strQuery = "insert into vishalc.[Rental Table] (Car_Id_Reference, UserName, CarName,Price,startdate,enddate)" +
            " values(@carid, @username, @carname,@price,@startdate,@enddate)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", gvrow.Cells[0].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", gvrow.Cells[1].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carname", gvrow.Cells[2].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         //I want to store ID for this row after insert command   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Select Scope_Identity() with Execute Scalar:

```
int returnID = 0;
string strQuery = "insert into vishalc.[Rental Table] (Car_Id_Reference, UserName,  
   CarName,Price,startdate,enddate)" + " values(@carid, @username, 
   @carname,@price,@startdate,@enddate); Select Scope_Identity()";
...
returnID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Steve Insert one more column in your table with uniqueidentifier as datatype , and add Guid id to the column in codebehind which is uniquely identifiable

to creat GUID

```
// This code example demonstrates the Guid.NewGuid() method. 

using System;

class CreateGUID
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    Guid g;
// Create and display the value of two GUIDs.
    g = Guid.NewGuid();
    Console.WriteLine(g);
    Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}

/*
This code example produces the following results:

0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e
7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7

*/
```

Above code is just for your reference to check the unique id generated each time now your code look like below

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvuserdata.Rows)
        {
Guid uniqueRowId = Guid.NewGuid();


            string strQuery = "insert into vishalc.[Rental Table] (uniqueRowId, Car_Id_Reference, UserName, CarName,Price,startdate,enddate)" +
            " values(@uniqueRowId,@carid, @username, @carname,@price,@startdate,@enddate)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);    
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqueRowId", uniqueRowId);    
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", gvrow.Cells[0].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", gvrow.Cells[1].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carname", gvrow.Cells[2].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate",gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;``
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         //I want to store ID for this row after insert command   
        }
```

NOTE: Make sure that you have update the column in the TABLE

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how retrieve the newly inserted record in the DB right? if that is the case your can fetch your by using the Scope_Identity()

```
int returnID = 0;
string strQuery = "insert into vishalc.[Rental Table] (Car_Id_Reference, UserName,     CarName,Price,startdate,enddate)" + 
" values(@carid, @username, @carname,@price,@startdate,@enddate); Select Scope_Identity()";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataReader reader = new SqlDataReader();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
returnId = reader("Car_Id_Reference")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding output parameter and [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) output parameter:

```
int RetVal = 0;

foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvuserdata.Rows)
{

    string strQuery = "insert into vishalc.[Rental Table] (Car_Id_Reference, UserName, CarName,Price,startdate,enddate)" +
    " values(@carid, @username, @carname,@price,@startdate,@enddate);set @out=SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", gvrow.Cells[0].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", gvrow.Cells[1].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carname", gvrow.Cells[2].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", gvrow.Cells[5].Text);

    SqlParameter outpar = new SqlParameter("@out", SqlDbType.Int);
    outpar.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(outpar);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (outpar != null)
        RetVal = Convert.ToInt32(outpar.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must set the primarykey  and Identity="yes" in your column.

Then you can use scopIdentity

```
string strQuery = "insert into vishalc.[Rental Table] (Car_Id_Reference, UserName, CarName,Price,startdate,enddate)" +
            " values(@carid, @username, @carname,@price,@startdate,@enddate); **Select Scope_Identity();**";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", gvrow.Cells[0].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", gvrow.Cells[1].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carname", gvrow.Cells[2].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
         **Guid Id=(Guid)(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());**
```

See this below line

**Guid Id=(Guid)(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())**

You want to guid .So I am converted to guid .